# Member variable vs. function concept checking

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I indulge myself in some early Sunday C++20 shenanigans and whilst playing with gcc/clang trunk concepts I stumbled upon a problem I fail to see an elegant solution for. Consider this code:

```
template <typename T>
concept floating_point = std::is_floating_point_v<std::decay_t<T>>;

template <typename T>
concept indexable = requires(T v)
{
    {v[0]} -> floating_point;
    {v[1]} -> floating_point;
    {v[2]} -> floating_point;
};

template <typename T>
concept func_indexable = requires(T v)
{
    {v.x()} -> floating_point;
    {v.y()} -> floating_point;
    {v.z()} -> floating_point;
};

template <typename T>
concept name_indexable = requires(T v)
{
    {v.x} -> floating_point;
    {v.y} -> floating_point;
    {v.z} -> floating_point;
};

template <typename T>
concept only_name_indexable = name_indexable<T> && !indexable<T>;

template <typename T>
concept only_func_indexable = func_indexable<T> && !indexable<T> && !name_indexable<T>;

void test_indexable(indexable auto v) {
    std::cout << v[0] << " " << v[1] << " " << v[2] << "\n";
}

void test_name_indexable(only_name_indexable auto v) {
    std::cout << v.x << " " << v.y << " " << v.z << "\n";
}

void test_func_indexable(only_func_indexable auto v) {
    std::cout << v.x() << " " << v.y() << " " << v.z() << "\n";
}
```

[(obligatory godbolt for toying with this)](https://godbolt.org/z/gyCAQn) https://godbolt.org/z/gyCAQn

Now consider a struct/class that satisfies `only_func_indexable`: Having member functions `x()`, `y()` and `z()` immediately lead to a compile error in the concept check for `name_indexable`. More precisely:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void test_func_indexable(auto:3) [with auto:3 = func_point]':

<source>:125:26:   required from here

<source>:29:6: error: 'decltype' cannot resolve address of overloaded function

   29 |     {v.x} -> floating_point;
```

This is kinda obvious since `.x` refers to the name of the member function which is an illegal expression inside of a `decltype`. Note also that changing `name_indexable`'s definition to

```
template <typename T>
concept name_indexable = !func_indexable<T> && requires(T v)
{
    {v.x} -> floating_point;
    {v.y} -> floating_point;
    {v.z} -> floating_point;
};
```

fixes the problem by means of lazy conjunction evaluation.

The takeaway for me at this point is: "Whenever I want to check the existence of a member variable I **have** to first provide and check a concept for the non-existence of a similarly named member function".

Now this feels rather awkward and just like a setting the fine folks in the ISO groups had a more elegant solution for in mind.

Just what would that solution be in this case?

Best,
Richard

Comment: If a type has a member-function named `x` it shouldn't also have a member-variable named the same thing. So why would you ever need to check for both the existens of the member-function and the non-existence of the member-variable?

Comment: not sure if its elegant but you can use nested requirements and do something like `requires(floating_point<decltype(a.x)>)` instead of `{v.x} -> floating_point;` inside requires expression.

Comment: There is no need for both to exist, merely checking a type that *only* has the member functions result in the type error (see the linked godbolt). The solution using decltype(a.x) should also not work given that that is illegal and the actual error.

Comment: @RichardVock i meant to say `v.x` instead of `a.x` also it should work as `v` depends on template type and compilation errors for variables in `template context` inside `requires` evaluate it to `false`, also `{v.x} -> floating_point` seems to compile in `clang` trunk, so i am not sure if its the problem in `GCC` itself or `clang`

Comment: @Gaurav Dhiman As I understand it `requires(floating_point<decltype(v.x)>)` is what `{v.x} -> floating_point;` compiles to, so I do not see the point of doing it that way. You are completely right though that it does indeed compile in clang. Odd. If comilation errors are actually ignored as false (like for SFINAE) then this entire question would indeed boil down to a compiler error :).

Comment: @RichardVock yes you are right `{v.x} -> floating_point;` is equivalent to `requires(floating_point<decltype((v.x))>);`, and since `v` appears inside `templated entity` although i am not sure but it can be a bug in gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your problem is really a problem. You will hopefully never have a type having both a data member `x` and a member function `x`, so your `func_indexable` is already `only_func_indexable`, and with that concept, there are no problems.

But if you want to be extremely exact there, you could do some thing like this

```
requires std::is_member_object_pointer_v<decltype(&T::x)> && floating_point<std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&T::x), T>>;
```

Of course this should be packed into some concepts and not written everytime. Note that `std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&T::x), T>` gives (some reference to) `float` for both `float x;` and `float x();`.

Comment: As stated in my comment above there is no need to have both defined in order to trigger the compile error. But `std::is_member_object_pointer` is a good tip and in fact new to me.